# Web site/web development for ipad

Tags: ipad

Is there any good example/tutorial sites where I can refer to regarding building website/web development for IPAD and possibly using HTML5 features?

-Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could start with this:

[Web Development For The iPhone And iPad: Getting Started](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/05/28/web-development-for-the-iphone-and-ipad-getting-started/)

Good luck!